# What could be meant with stringified hex format?

Tags: python, string-formatting, uuid

The following code converts an UUID into "stringified hex format". I do not really understand what it does and how I could rewrite it in the new `str.format` style.

```
    if not isinstance(value, uuid.UUID):
        return "%.32x" % uuid.UUID(value).int
    else:
        # hexstring
        return "%.32x" % value.int
```

It is taken from the [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/custom_types.html?highlight=guid#backend-agnostic-guid-type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It basically writes the `uuid` without the hypens. For example if this was how I got a uuid, I could provide the following representations

```
>>> value = uuid.uuid4()
>>> value
UUID('aa56cc68-01ca-49c6-a0dc-4f7104a9ee83')
>>> print(value)
aa56cc68-01ca-49c6-a0dc-4f7104a9ee83
>>> value.int
226419442665111776416141721028184895107
>>> "%.32x" % value.int
'aa56cc6801ca49c6a0dc4f7104a9ee83'
```

We can see that both `__str__` and `__repr__` produce representations of the uuid in hex, but joined by hyphens. The `int` value is in decimal, so this function provides the hex representations, but without the hyphens.

Comment: Thank you! How could I accomplish the same thing without the old string formatting style?

Comment: Once you have a `UUID` object you can just use `value.hex` it will produce the same result

Answer (score 0):

It means that the UUID is composed of binary data which is not directly printable. So to be able to handle it as a string it is converted to a string of hexadecimal characters (0 - 9, a - f). Each 2 characters represent a byte of data.